# How do you find FIDE rated tournaments?

Tags: tournament, fide

I guess this is a more practical question. I have managed to get a FIDE ID from my country’s chess federation (ECF). but I’m not sure how exactly I’m supposed to register for FIDE-rated tournaments. I found [this](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?country=ENG)  site, but I don’t know where I should be signing up for one of these. I appreciate any help from anyone that has experience with this.

Answer (score 2):

All FIDE rated tournaments have to be registered in advance with FIDE. How long before varies according to the type of tournament but this means that FIDE know in advance when a tournament will be and they publish this information on their website.

The general page is [here](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml). This includes a drop down box at the top which allows you to select a particular country / federation and see the upcoming tournaments in your country.

So, for instance, if I select "USA" and click "Search" I get this [page](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=USA) which shows "Tournaments Registered for February 2022" for the USA. This confusing title means that these tournaments are registered to report their results in time for inclusion in the February rating list. This means that tournaments which are due to finish during January in time for the organiser / arbiter to submit results before the end of January will be included. Tournaments which finished in the last few days of December will also be included where there wasn't enough time for December submission.

Comment: Thanks. So for these tournaments can I just turn up or do I have to register in advance? And if so, how would I do that?

Comment: You need to find where the particular tournament you want to enter publishes its entry form, get a copy, fill it in and return it with your entry fee. If it is run by a chess club then the club website would be a good place to look first.